# Find last n for which 2^n has a 0.

Tags: number-theory

Find last number $n$ for which $2^n$ has a zero. For example $2^{10}=1024$ has a zero for which last number zero will be there. (It is possible that there doesn't exist such limits to $n$ but what is the proof?)

Comment: Is this homework? What have you tried?

Comment: How are you defining last $n$? Additionally, how do you handle fractional cases as $2^{-12}=0.00024414062$ that has a 0 and is a rather small number compared to others.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By Euler's theorem, $2^{20k}\equiv1\pmod{25}\implies 2^{20k+2}\equiv04\pmod{100}$, so..

Comment: (L=Little, contrary to L=Last.)

Comment: This is such a far better approach than my own it's not even funny.

Comment: That's brilliant!What was your motivation behind this solution?Did you first think about showing that there are infinitely many powers of two with zero as the second-to-last digit?Also,can we not comment using Euler's totient theorem that $2^{40k}\equiv 1\pmod {100}$ and the result follows?

Comment: @rah4927 $2$ is not comprime to $100$.

Comment: Well,we can't since (2,100) is not 1.

Comment: @Asaf thanks, your comment made me realize that I was really using Euler's theorem here

Comment: Hehe, you're welcome!

Comment: @rah4927 Just as a note: the result you'd hoped for there is very silly, since the left-hand side is a power of two, and the right-hand side says that our number is odd!

Comment: @Mike,yes,I made a rather silly error.

Comment: @Mike Thanks, your solutions brings some interesting questions about the density barto was talking about :) (actually, it is a complete question in math.se!)

Comment: @rah yes pretty much,when I read the question the first time I thought(for some unknown reason) that it was asking for a power of two ending in $0$, and I was about to comment there is none. Then i saw it asked for *some* 0, and the second-from-right seemed vulnerable :)

Comment: Another question.How do you jump from $2^{20k}\equiv 1\pmod 25$ to $2^{20k+2}\equiv 4\pmod 100$?I know we can get this using CRT,but I am assuming there is a cleverer way.

Comment: @rah4927 Multiply both sides by four :)

Comment: @Mike,yes,but multiplying both sides by 4 shouldn't have any effect on the modulus.How does 25 change to 100 without using CRT?

Comment: @rah4927 Recall what modulus means: it means that $2^{20k}=1+25n$ for some $n \in \Bbb Z$. So $2^{20k+2}=4+100n$ for some $n \in \Bbb Z$.

Comment: @Mike,oh right.Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**: Prove that infinitely many $2^n$ will start with $10$.

Comment: How to prove this? I am confused.

Comment: Pigeonhole?I can't see a way to use it.

Comment: Since $\log_{10}2$ is irrational, the set $\{\{n\log_{10}2\}:n\in\mathbb Z^+\}$ is dense in $[0,1]$. (You can prove this with the Pigeon Hole Principle for any irrational number.) Knowing this, try to show that $2^n$ can start with $10$ when written in decimal.

Comment: @barto: Using $\{x\}$ to denote the fractional part while using $\{\ldots\}$ to denote a set is an effective example of when operator overloading is bad. Perhaps writing $x-\lfloor x\rfloor$ is better for readability.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I see. It is unfortunate that there is no other symbol in use for the fractional part. It would be tedious to write $x-\lfloor x\rfloor$ every time.

Comment: @barto: I agree, and I understand your plight. But that's life... :\

Comment: @barto I've occasionally seen $\mod 1$ used as shorthand for the fractional part.